# Advice for improving chances of reopening of my question about XML processing

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

[How to programmatically fix an XML document based on maxLength restrictions in the schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72365267/how-to-programmatically-fix-an-xml-document-based-on-maxlength-restrictions-in-t)

Immediately after posting and receiving down- and close-votes, I edited the question to provide focus, research, and code.

A day later it was closed anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure that I agree with the current close reason *Needs More Focus*, but it does seem to be seeking recommendations for libraries the way its worded. I would remove the language around being "open to any libraries or custom implementation" to avoid reclosure since it is on the cusp of being reopened.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest yes thanks, i see the point. i had removed the sentence before. i am actually not looking for library recommendations, but for any way at all to achieve it. i wrote this because i was afraid that my sample code would cause people not to consider any other options than what i attempted.